# Haskell JSON Rest API — how to generically serialize meta information?

Tags: json, haskell

I'm creating a JSON REST API (lots of caps there), and already have Data.Aeson.Generic working nicely. In the following, serializedString would be `{"x":10, "y":10}`

```
import qualified Data.Aeson.Generic as A
import Data.Data (Data, Typeable)
data Unit = Unit { x :: Int, y :: Int } deriving (Show, Eq, Data, Typeable)

example = do
    let serializedByteString = A.encode (Unit 10 10)
```

I would like to have my api respond like this for successes:

```
{unit:{x:10, y:10}}
```

And this for failures

```
{error:"Didn't work!"}
```

I was thinking of making some kind of `Response` data type, with `Response` and `Error` constructors. It's easy to serialize `Error`, but response could have all kinds of different objects, and rather than send back `{data:{...}}` I'd like to do `{unit:{...}}`.

Is there a way to define my `Response` value constructor so that it works with anything deriving `Data`? Is there a way to know what the name of the value constructor is when I go to serialize my object? `show` knows it somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't work for the Error constructor yet (I think), but this works for unit

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveDataTypeable #-}

module Types where

import Data.Data (Data, Typeable, typeOf)
import Data.Aeson (ToJSON(..), (.=), object)
import qualified Data.Aeson.Generic as AG

import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Char (toLower)

data Unit = Unit { x :: Int, y :: Int } deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)


data Message a = Message { obj :: a } |
                 Error String 
                 deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)


instance (Data a, Typeable a) => ToJSON (Message a) where
    toJSON m = object [T.pack typeName .= AG.toJSON (obj m)]
        where o = obj m
              typeName = map toLower $ show $ typeOf o
```

You have to use Data.Aeson.encode, rather than Data.Aeson.Generic.encode on the top-level message. The key concept I was missing was typeOf from Data.Data.Typeable. It gives you a string representing the data constructor. It will be interesting to try to go the other direction using FromJSON

Edit: to be clear, you can then call `Data.Aeson.encode $ Message $ Unit 10 10` and get `{unit:{x:10, y:10}}`